# sentence lacking a main verb

Tags: sentence-construction, style

The following is taken from [a CNN transcript](https://transcripts.cnn.com/show/fmjc/date/2022-09-20/segment/01). As you can see, it lacks a main verb. Is it natural?
What's the reason for not including a main verb?

> On the edge of town, the remains of Russia's once vaunted army, before a monument harking back to a different time, which now seems like the distant past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a transcript of the audio (what you hear) part of a TV news broadcast. At the time indicated, clearly, the video (what you see) must show some scene of e.g. wreckage or discarded items left by the Russian army. The speaker's voice states what is being seen. Like a caption for a picture (e.g. 'London's famous Tower Bridge, over the River Thames') a complete sentence with a main verb is not required.

Comment: Yes, a series of noun phrases, a lack of complete sentences, a common format for describing things, a resulting poetic and dramatic effect